# Creating a secondary delete option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've create a table that gets populated with status_updates by the user over time. Each status can be deleted individually.

This is accomplished by calling the destroy method in the status_update_controller and having the particular status_update identified in a private method called correct_user.

So basically it looks like this:

At the top of my status_update_controller

```
before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy
```

The destroy method

```
def destroy
    @status_update.destroy
    redirect_to root_url
end
```

and the private correct user method

```
private

    def correct_user
      @status_update = current_user.status_update.find_by_id(params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @status_update.nil?
    end
```

---

My question is this:

How can I select all of the status_updates for a particular user and destroy them using a button or link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define inside your `StatusUpdatesController` an action like this:

```
def delete_all
  current_user.status_updates.delete_all
end
```

You will need to route to this action also:

```
resources :status_updates do
  collection do
    delete :delete_all
  end
end
```

And to make a button:

```
button_to "Delete the everything", delete_all_status_updates_path, :method => :delete
```

Comment: ok great. This actually demonstrates how the link_to feature works a bit better for me.

Although, I'm getting this error:

No route matches [POST] "/status_updates/delete_all"...

In the method: part of link_to.. whenever I change it to :delete nothing gets deleted, but the pages is routed to the root. 

If I put 'post' as you recommended it gives the same error I mentioned. If I put :delete_all is also gives the error.

Comment: I used the wrong method in the button to. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: ok. I got it to route to the delete_all action inside with right controller.

Comment: yep. I saw that. No biggie though. You helped a lot! Thanks!